# Difficulty adding a inputscope to a TextBox within a StackPanel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend, inputscope

So I'm trying to improve the functionality on a text box, by adding a 'text' style input scope on this occasion, later I will need to add a 'currency' inputscope.

I'm using EB4 as its easier to get direct access to contents within a stack panel, however I keep getting greeted with various errors, even after I follow Bob Tabors Tutorial ( http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Adding-Different-Input-Scopes)

See screenshot:

[image: Screenshoot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about WP7 input scopes but regarding the error in the screenshot  it's due to an invalid closing tag :

```
<TextBox x:Name="NameTb">
    ...
<TextBox x:Name="NameTb"/>
```

Should be

```
<TextBox x:Name="NameTb">
    ...
</TextBox>
```

Comment: This worked, but when I tried to do the same with currencyAmount on the next text box, I'm getting another error -__-  http://s10.postimage.org/wi9nrxrc9/error.png

Comment: You're missing a caps there, it's `TextBox`, not `textBox`.